# How do I wrap text around image with a colored text box?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Teyl.jpg)
I am trying to have an image aligned left with a colored text box that overlaps (positioned off-center) to the image. I can get that by creating a div class="mycontainer" with div class= my text-box" and css (see below), but I can't seem to figure out how to make text wrap around the colored text box. It wraps around the image, but keeps pushing the text box down.

```
.mycontainer {
 position: relative;
 font-family: Arial;
 width: 100%;  
}

.mytext-block {
 position:absolute;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 150px;
 background-color:turquoise;
 color: black;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: read about `shape-outside`, it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rachel here is a way to wrap text around an image which is inset into a colored box.

```css
.mycontainer {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 670px;
}

.mytext-block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: turquoise;
  color: black;
}

#image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: -190px;
  shape-outside: content-box;
  margin: 140px -170px 0 0;
}

#text {
  font-size: 140%;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycontainer">
  <div class="mytext-block"></div>
  <img id="image" src="https://lorempixel.com/300/100/">
  <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellen tesque placerat dolor sed dolor euismod hendrerit. Integer eget elit nibh. Vestibulum posuere. Sed elementum bibendum magna, nec tempus augue egestas quis. Pellentesque lacus justo, vehicula vitae nisl sed, semper euismod dui.
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Click the "Run code snippet" below to see it.  Hope this helps. -->
```